# Dockerfile with nesting via non-master branches

Tags: docker, dockerfile, nvidia

I have few Dockerfile images with the following nesting:

MyImage (master) `FROM shalakhin/base` -> Base (master) `FROM centos7`

Is it possible to do:

MyImage (gpu) `FROM shalakhin/base:gpu` -> Base (gpu) `FROM centos7:gpu`?

I need that because master branch has default configuration while I want to support nvidia-docker image that must use not centos7 but centors-cuda base.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to use a different `:tag` for an image when it's based on another source image?  Then yes, people mix windows and linux containers under the same repo with different `:tags`

Comment: @Matt I mean is it possible to use git branches in FROM instead of tags? If I have 2 branches and zero tags.